# How to forbid certain artifacts from being used in certain projects?

Tags: java, maven

For example, the licensing might expire soon and we want to enforce everyone to find an alternative.
Another example is when it is known then that a library is not secure (thus, some alternative library has to be used).

I have read this documentation:
https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html

What I meant is if there is a way to validate artifacts of a project against a remote (internal-company) server somewhere to see if any of the artifacts are banned or not.

Comment: We wrote something like that ourselves. Jfrog Xray can  also help you with that.

Comment: It seems with JFrog Xray, "they" will decide whether the component is secure or not. For us, there is also a situation where we do not want to use a certain component anymore because it's already End of Life; not because it is vulnerable. So, sometimes we want to "manually" forbid certain artifacts. I haven't read the whole documentations yet. Maybe it's mentioned there somewhere.

Comment: Anyway, if you want you can post your answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFrog Xray allows you to filter for *their* security lists as well as to blacklist/whitelist other artifacts (with your own custom messages).

https://jfrog.com/xray/